# Estimate on integral of cosine on a set of positive measure

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory

I would like to find an estimate of the form
$$
\left|\int_S \cos(\theta)d\theta\right|\leq A<|S|
$$
for a positive measure set $S\subset [0,2\pi)$ and $|S|$ the Lebesgue measure of the set $S$. I.e. an estimate that takes advantage of the oscillations of cosine to beat the trivial estimate, ideally I would like to find the optimal constant $A$.

Somehow I am not seeing the argument.

Comment: What are some easily accesible properties of your $S$? It seems that $|S|$ is one, but what other properties are allowed to be used for estimation? In other words, if the whole of $S$ is known, then you can simply write the exact value. So, how much do we know about $S$?

Comment: @cnikbesku only that it has positive Lebesgue measure, unfortunately. I'm not sure what you mean by the "whole of S," of course if it is a union of intervals, you can write things down explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There cannot be any such $A$. Take $S=(0,\frac  1n)$ to get $\cos (\frac 1n ) \frac  1n \leq A <\frac  1n$ for every $n$. This gives $0 \leq A \leq 0$ in the limit so $A=0$. But then you get $\int_S \cos \theta d\theta=0$ for every set $S$ of positive measure, which is false.

Comment: Very nice, thank you.